# NFC: Unable to open NFC Device

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, nfc

I have a ACR 122U-A9 NFC Reader and I am trying to have it connect to libnfc on Windows. I downloaded [libnfc-win64](https://github.com/peacepenguin/libnfc-unofficialbuilds) and I added `libnfc.conf` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\libnfc\config`. The bottom of this file contains:

> device.name = "ftdiPn532"
>
> device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/ttyUSB0"

When I run `nfc-scan-device -v` I get the following output:

> nfc-scan-device uses libnfc 1.7.1 1 NFC device(s) found:
>
> error  libnfc.driver.pn532_uart        Invalid serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
>
> nfc_open failed for pn532_uart:/dev/ttyUSB0

How do I find the connstring for my device? It is connected via USB and Windows is recognizing the device as 'ACR122 Smart Card Reader'

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here for connection string issues with libnfc on Windows 10, here is how it works:

Instead of `/dev/tty`, on Windows there should be the COM port number (e.g. `pn532_uart:COM3:115200`).

If you don't add a config file, libnfc will autoscan and find the correct device by itself.